# Trim string, but return the number of spaces removed from the start

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, trim

I need to find out how many characters were removed from the start of the string, which is the value of a textarea input, so I can determine the new start position of the cursor selection.

`$.trim()` will do the trim, but how can I find out how many chars were taken from the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick

```
var numberOfStartWS = yourOrigString.match(/^(\s*)/)[1].length;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `indexOf()` method to find the occurance of the trimmed version in the original string.

```
var string = "  aaa";
var trimmed = $.trim(string); // aaa;
var diff = string.indexOf(trimmed); // 2;
```

You cannot simply compare the lengths, as spaces may have been trimmed from the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the lengths of the trimmed string and the non-trimmed string will be the number of characters that were trimmed.

Comment: if and only if there were no white spaces at the end of the string ... but the OP asked for _number of characters removed from the start of the string_

Comment: +1: Yes, of course under this presumption, which I assumed was obvious enough to omit.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you take the length of the string before you trim and then do a diff between the new trimmed string?